# Find the missing brick, again

Tags: pattern, visual, progressive-matrix

[image: Find the missing brick again]

The pattern made up of fig. *a* to *i* is missing the last brick. What figure, out of the figures in range *1* to *9*, is the last brick to restore the pattern, and why?

*Created by myself*

Answer (score 1):

Assuming there's lots of extraneous noise, which there certainly appears to be, you could argue the following...

> Firstly, notice that there is a diagonal pattern of the white background shapes. This means that the missing **i** will have a blank background, which doesn't help us, but maybe it hints that diagonals are important.

Now, using the following image as a guide:

> [image: red & blue]

In this, you can see that

> the squares with blank backgrounds (and thus, **i**) have arrow shapes (circled in red). This limits us to options **4**, **8**, & **9**.

Additionally,

> There's a pattern of cross shapes (circled in blue) that follows the same diagonal, but instead of repeating based on the background, is mirrored around the centre. The central diagonal from bottom left to top right has **x** crosses (dark blue). The next diagonals out have **+** crosses (light blue), leaving the top left (**a**) and bottom right (**i**) with no cross (aqua). This limits us to options **1**, **7**, & **9**.

Ignoring everything else, the only option that fits both those observations is

> option **9**.

...of course with so much going on, I wouldn't be surprised if you could find more equally valid interpretations.